# Why regex engine choose to match pattern `..X` from `.X|..X|X.`?

Tags: regex, alternation

I have a string

```
1234X5678
```

and I use this regex to match pattern

```
.X|..X|X.
```

I got

```
34X
```

The question is why didn't I get `4X` or `X5`?

Why regex choose to perform the second pattern?

Comment: What is your expected output? 1234,5678?

Comment: Because that's not the way that regex engines (Traditional NFA) work.

Comment: Quick guess -- regex is trying a greedy match?

Comment: With `or` It should match the first pattern and ignore the rest because of `true|... == true` doesn't need to evaluate the second pattern.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/aW1yK5/1 take a look at the regex debugger and see how it works ;)

Comment: @terces907: Regex OR and AND don't necessarily act as short-circuiting logic operators.

Comment: I love these questions. I answered a similar one an hour ago. Please check. **Regex engine analyzes the input from LEFT TO RIGHT.** And this is not an atomic group you are using. Also POSIX would return the same result here.

Comment: One alternative way is using look-around (positive look-ahead) `r'(?=(.{1,2}X|X.))'`

Comment: I think I know the reason now, and I just answered some similar question like this. Sorry for my confusion. Thanks for your discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main point here is:

**Regex engine analyzes the input from LEFT TO RIGHT by default.**

So, you have an alternation pattern `.X|..X|X.` and you run it against `1234X5678`. [See what happens](https://regex101.com/r/lS2vI8/1):

[image]

*Each alternative branch is tested against each location in the string from left to right*.

The first 1-7 steps show how the engine tries to match the characters at the beginning of the string. However, none of the branches (neither `.X`, nor `..X`, nor `X.` match `12` or `123`).

Steps 8-13 just repeat the same failing scenario as none of the branches match `23` or `234`.

Steps 14-19 show a success scenario because the `34X` can be matched with Branch 2 (`..X`).

**The regex engine does not reach the location before `4` since this location gets matched and *consumed*.**

And another conclusion:

**The order of alternations matters, and in NFA regex engines the first alternative matched wins, BUT this alternative does not have to be the first shortest one, a farther longer alternative *that matches the same characters in the beginning* can match earlier.**

Comment: What tool do you use to visualize the string matching process?

Comment: I forgot to add it: [regex101.com, *regex debugger* section](https://regex101.com/r/lS2vI8/1). Added now.