# Regexp Scan results

Tags: ruby, regex

does anybody knows why I am getting different results depending on the order of the patterns?

```
list1 = ["AA1", "AA2","AA", "AA+"]
list2 = ["AA1", "AA2","AA+", "AA"]
results1 = "somethin with AA+ in it".scan(Regexp.union(list1))
results2 = "somethin with AA+ in it".scan(Regexp.union(list2))
```

Results1 outputs "AA"
Results2 outputs "AA+"

I may be misunderstandig how scan works, but I was expecting it to return every occurrence, hence both "AA" and "AA+". Also I don't get why the ouptut changes depending on the order of the strings used.

Comment: Unanchored alternation group matches the first branch, once a branch matches the others are not tested.

Comment: I don't think `Regexp.union()` is doing what you think it is. It creates a single regular expression that matches any of the provided expressions. It does not loop over the list and run one regular expression match at a time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In an alternation group in NFA regex, the first left-most branch "wins". See [*Alternation with The Vertical Bar or Pipe Symbol*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager) for a more detailed explanation.

The [regexes you have](http://ideone.com/aai6Ps) are

Regex 1: `(?-mix:AA1|AA2|AA|AA\+)`
Regex 2: `(?-mix:AA1|AA2|AA\+|AA)`

If you use the first regex, you get `AA` because `|AA|` branch matches first, and the others are not tested against the input, the match is returned and the regex index advances.

The second regex yields `AA+` because the `|AA\+|` matches first, and the match is returned, `|AA` is not even tested.

Comment: Some related posts: [*Alternation usage creates strange behavior*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35987637/alternation-usage-creates-strange-behavior/35987686#35987686) and [*Why regex engine choose to match pattern `..X` from `.X|..X|X.`?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35946342/why-regex-engine-choose-to-match-pattern-x-from-x-xx/35950170#35950170)

Comment: Downvoting for a reason is a way to enrich everyone's knowledge. What is the reason for a downvote here?